# trocar char Z por S entre vogais em uma string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Como posso fazer para trocar todas as ocorrências da letra Z entre S dentro de uma string

por exemplo

> TEREZA , CEZAR, BRAZIL, ANZOL

ficaria

> TERESA , CESAR, BRASIL, ANZOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar dois grupos para verificar a existencia das vogais entre o `Z`, depois de capturados basta jogar eles `$1`(primeiro grupo), `$2`(segundo grupo) entre o `S`

```
$str = 'TEREZA , CEZAR, BRAZIL, ANZOL';
echo preg_replace('/(A|I|O|U|E)Z(A|I|O|U|E)/', '$1S$2', $str);
```

Comment: podes usar `([AIOUE])`. :D

Answer (score 5):

### Via lookback

```
preg_replace('~(?<=[a-zA-Z])Z(?=[a-zA-Z])~', 'S', $str);
```

#### Explicação

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` - vai observar os que vem antes, mas não capturar.
- Z - carácter literal que deve ser capturado.
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` - vai verificar o que vem depois, mas não capturar.

### Via grupo

```
preg_replace('~([a-zA-Z])Z([a-zA-Z])~', '$1S$2', $str);
```

#### Explicação

- `([a-zA-Z])` - grupo 1 que deve deve ser capturado
- Z - carácter literal que deve ser capturado
- `([a-zA-Z])` - grupo 2 que deve deve ser capturado
- `$1S$2` - substitui pelo que foi capturado no grupo1+S+que foi capturado no grupo2

Comment: Perfeito, a primeira regex troca `AZAZA` por `ASASA`, já a segunda deixa `ASAZA`. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Usando lista de vogais:**

```
$input = ['TEREZA' , 'CEZAR', 'BRAZIL', 'ANZOL'];
print_r(preg_replace('/([aeiou]+)z([aeiou]+)/i', '$1S$2', $input));
```

ou:

```
echo preg_replace('/([aeiou]+)z([aeiou]+)/i', '$1S$2', 'BRAZIL');
```

**Resultado:**

> Array ( [0] => TERESA [1] => CESAR [2] => BRASIL [3] => ANZOL )
>
> BRASIL